# Separate a string by a wildcard in python

Tags: python, string, partition

I have a file that looks like

```
 12 MG   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01  0.000000000000E+00
 16 S     1.558454815345E-01  1.558454815345E-01  2.500000000000E-01
  8 O     2.189546044408E-01 -1.271822846411E-01  4.012978695812E-01
```

and I want to separate out the numbers from the front of the line, with an output of

```
MG   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01  0.000000000000E+00
S     1.558454815345E-01  1.558454815345E-01  2.500000000000E-01
O     2.189546044408E-01 -1.271822846411E-01  4.012978695812E-01
```

I have this

```
for line in file:
    head, sep, tail = line.partition('wildcard')
    print tail
```

What should I put in for the wildcard?

Comment: That looks like a fixed-width format to me; can you confirm that the 3rd line is padded with one extra space compared to the previous two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use,

```
head, sep, tail = line.strip().partition(" ")
```

The whole program becomes like this

```
with open("Input.txt") as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        print line.strip().partition(" ")[2]
```

**Output**

```
MG   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01  0.000000000000E+00
S     1.558454815345E-01  1.558454815345E-01  2.500000000000E-01
O     2.189546044408E-01 -1.271822846411E-01  4.012978695812E-01
```

Answer (score 6):

Your format looks like a fixed-column format, where each column is of a fixed width.

If so, use slicing instead:

```
for line in file:
    print line[4:]
```

to slice off the first 4 characters.

Alternatively, split on whitespace once, with the `None` argument to `str.split()`:

```
for line in file:
    tail = line.split(None, 1)[-1]
    print tail
```

`str.split(None)` *skips* whitespace at the start of the string and splits on the first sequence of whitespace characters after the first column. `[-1]` takes the last element; even if there is no more than one column on the line you'll get a result.

Demo:

```
>>> line = ' 16 S     1.558454815345E-01  1.558454815345E-01  2.500000000000E-01\n'
>>> line.split(None, 1)
['16', 'S     1.558454815345E-01  1.558454815345E-01  2.500000000000E-01\n']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text = '''12 MG   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01  0.000000000000E+00
 16 S     1.558454815345E-01  1.558454815345E-01  2.500000000000E-01
  8 O     2.189546044408E-01 -1.271822846411E-01  4.012978695812E-01'''


for line in text.splitlines():
    print line.split(None,1)[1]
```

result

```
MG   -5.000000000000E-01 -5.000000000000E-01  0.000000000000E+00
S     1.558454815345E-01  1.558454815345E-01  2.500000000000E-01
O     2.189546044408E-01 -1.271822846411E-01  4.012978695812E-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it yourself, you could also use a library: NumPy's I/O routines (`loadtxt`) are very useful for parsing such files.

In your case, you'd have to specifiy a record data type (`dtype` parameter, see [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)).